# How to add local calendar instead of julian in udacity sunshine app

Tags: android, calendar

i want to use my local calendar (Ethiopian Calendar) instead of Julian Calendar in android Udacity sunshine app. Could any one help me, please.

Comment: What do you speak about? About Ethiopian calendar or about Ethiopian language and locale? Two very different things. Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Thank You for ur reply, i need to use ethiopian calendar on the Udacity Course, sunshine application.

Comment: I am not aware of any available Ethiopian-calendar implementation as subclass of `java.util.Calendar` in general. And I am sure that Android only supports `GregorianCalendar` nothing else (see source code of Android-Java). However, there are some external libraries which offer such an Ethiopian calendar (ICU4J, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/chrono/EthiopicChronology.html) and [Time4J](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/EthiopianCalendar.html), last one written by me).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you'r looking for.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
```

This would be the french calendar you can find ethiopian or the closest to it.